# elastic beanstalk nodejs v18 2 issues

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Elastic Beanstalk used to be amazing. Would update within 2-3 minutes.

Now it takes 15 minutes to finish updating and it regularly fails and does rollbacks

This is literally what happens if I try to update the environment variables. 15 mintes, and a rollback. I set 1 new variable with a valid value.

I have no idea how to fix this.
[image]

I'm not a devops guy. I've got too much going on to properly learn all this stuff. Does anybody have any other reocmmendations for services I could use? I give up with AWS. This has been going on for all of 2023 now.

Comment: Try to navigate to the CloudFormation console and identify the resource that failed to update from the respective stack events.